# Usage of "and so"

Tags: word-usage

Take this as an example: 
I've a thought that - the life is worthless. Since the life is worthless, We're worthless. How to express this in a simple statement?
Is this correct to say?

> "Life is worthless and so we"

Help me! Thank you!

Comment: *And so* means *therefore*. You can say it as you have, but it will sound odd because *so* in that context often precedes the verb *be*: *so are we*. If you wish, *Life is worthless and therefore we as well* is a bit better (if you don't want to repeat the verb.)

Comment: @medica Then what about *so are we*? Can I say, *"life is worthless, so are we"*..?

Comment: It sound odd to my ear without the *and*, however, if you replace the comma with a semicolon (hard to do in *speech*), it is grammatical.

Comment: @medica okay.. *life is worthless and so are we* OR *life is worthless; so are we* - What is your choice..?

Comment: Wazir, it's *your* saying, lol! You have the final choice. :) They're both correct now.

Answer (score 1):

> Life is worthless and so are we

is grammatical but means

> Life is worthless and we are worthless

without one causing the other. To express what you mean, you should say

> Life is worthless, so we are worthless.